# How to create an enumeration that accepts a generic type as associated type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to create an enumeration that accepts a generic type as associated value.
The compiler complains:

> Reference to generic type 'GenericItem' requires arguments in <...>

The scheme is pretty simple:

```
struct GenericItem <Item:FormattableAsStringWithPrecision> {
    let value: Item
}

enum Enumeration {
    case Generic(values: [GenericItem])
}
```

I can't understand how to make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Generic type to the enum too, the types can be inferred from the initialiser so you do not need to pass it as a generic type argument.

Below is an example of how you might do it.

```
struct GenericItem<T: CustomDebugStringConvertible> {
  let value: T
}

enum Enumeration<T: CustomDebugStringConvertible> {
  case Generic(value: [GenericItem<T>])
}

let someValue = Enumeration.Generic(value: [ GenericItem(value: "") ])
```

edit: I changed the `FormattableAsStringWithPrecision` to `CustomDebugStringConvertible` as I assumed it was one of your own custom protocols which can be easily swapped out, but the same logic would still apply for any protocol.

Comment: @Andrea no worries - generics are hard, keep at it